# Keeping locked cells when copying a worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I copy an Excel worksheet, with protected cells, onto a new sheet and retain the locked cells? I have tried the normal protection sequences but every time I copy the sheet, the new sheet has the previously protected cells unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the tab with the sheet name and select *Move or Copy...*, you can copy the entire sheet to another workbook (by ticking *Create a copy* option) or create another sheet in the current workbook. This way you can keep the protection.

[image]

[image]

If you copy the protected cells with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste those cells into a new sheet, Excel cannot retain the protection by nature. You must do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work unless workbook is unprotected! The move or copy option is grayed out. I can not get the protection to copy to another sheet within the excel workbook. If you unprotect the workbook and just leave the sheet protected it will work. It will copy locked cells and formulas over to new sheet!

Answer (score 0):

Create new blank sheets. Instead of right clicking on the sheet tab and using the "Move or copy...", click in the upper left hand box (corner by row 1 and column A, with the triangle grayed). This selects the whole sheet. Copy it, click the tab or tabs of where you want it and paste it there. Protection will be included in your paste to the new sheets.